# Re-use prefetched data across multiple pages

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, react-query

I have a next.js app with two pages:

1. All blog posts page
2. Individual blog posts page template

The problem is that they are both separate pages that require the exact same data. I am using getStaticProps to get the blog posts but i am having to make the same exact request twice.

Is there anyway that i can just make one of those requests and then use that prefetched data elsewhere on my site?

Comment: I suggest you to research about Context API. ref: https://reactjs.org/docs/context.html

Comment: One option is to use Redux: save this data to the store and access it at any component if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, After researching more it turns out there is not a solution for this yet but many people are asking for it. Right now its suggested that you just call the api twice - You are likely prefetching the data anyway so its not a big deal.

Answer (score 0):

Now there is a library called SWR which automatically caches data when calling an API multiple times. Sounds like the perfect use case for you.

```
const fetcher = (...args) => fetch(...args).then(res => res.json())
const { data, error } = useSWR('/api/blogs', fetcher)
```

https://swr.vercel.app/#overview